# Adjust for multiple comparisons in several mixed models

Tags: mixed-model, multiple-comparisons, glmm, tukey-hsd-test

I am fitting several generalized mixed models with binomial family to model proportions data(dependent variable) and 3 factors.The data looks like this:

Sample Day ligand Condition Conc1 Conc2 .... Conc10

1    1    A       M      0.99    0.86 ....  0.0058

1    1    B       M      0.96    0.85 ....  0.0024

1    1    C       M      0.92    0.88 ....  0.0022

In each model I did post hoc analysis for comparing A vs B, A vs C, A vs D and A vs E for Day 1 and condition M and so on for all days and conditions separately using lsmeans with Tukey correction followed by contrast function in R. However, the it performed other comparisons like B vs C, B vs D, B vs E and so on which I am not interested in.

1) I am not quite sure how to give a contrast matrix for the comparisons that I am interested in with respect to each day and condition (for a three way comparison)

2) Is the Tukey correction applied with respect to all the other comparisons that I am not interested in?

3) Do I have to adjust again for the multiple comparisons across the models (across concentrations)?

Answer (score 1):

I’ll try to answer each...

> 1) I am not quite sure how to give a contrast matrix for the comparisons that I am interested in with respect to each day and condition (for a three way comparison)

Look at the documentation for `contrast`. There are several standard options provided besides `pairwise`. It looks like you want to use `trt.vs.ctrl`. In addition, there is the option of specifying a `by` variable.

> 2) Is the Tukey correction applied with respect to all the other comparisons that I am not interested in?

The default adjustment method for pairwise comparisons is the Tukey method. But other methods have different defaults, and the Tukey adjustment is inappropriate *except* with pairwise comparisons. I suggest ``adjust = “mvt”`, which is the exact 1-step adjustment for any family of contrasts — albeit computationally expensive.

> 3) Do I have to adjust again for the multiple comparisons across the models (across concentrations)?

I think people typically don’t, but it may be appropriate in your context. I’d need to know more to understand the best approach.

By the way, **lsmeans** is being deprecated in favor of the newer **emmeans** package. The latter has an assortment of vignettes with several examples (hopefully they are helpful).